# Why does creating a conda environment from a shell script cause the script to terminate early, and how can I fix this?

Tags: bash, shell, cmd, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create .sh and .cmd scripts that set up a conda environment. In the scripts, after creating the conda environment, I have additional commands to install some 'development mode' packages. However, the script exits after running the `conda env create` command (the environment is successfully created). Is there any way to ensure that the call to `conda env create` doesn't exit the script?

here is the code within the script:

```
# Clone repos to current directory
git clone https://github.com/int-brain-lab/ibllib.git --branch develop
git clone https://github.com/int-brain-lab/iblapps.git --branch develop
git clone https://github.com/int-brain-lab/analysis.git
git clone https://github.com/int-brain-lab/IBL-pipeline.git
# Create conda environment from the .yaml file and activate
conda env create -f iblenv.yaml python=3.8
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate iblenv
# Install repos in 'development mode'
conda-develop ./ibllib
conda-develop ./iblapps
conda-develop ./analysis
conda-develop ./IBL-pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe issue is here:
    source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
if conda.sh contains exit command, it will stop executing of your shell script because source means that conda.sh will be executed in the current process.

You can try to add echo before and after "source" command to check that "conda env create" is not the latest command.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, sorry for the late reply - yes I tried this and `conda env create` is the last command. would an option for me be to find a (safe) way to edit `conda.sh` so that it doesn't exit? Would you think this is ok?